# Set attribute value using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set the attribute of an element using javascript and not jQuery, the jQuery would be this, but how would the javascript be?

```
$("param[name='wmode']").attr("value","opaque");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) DOM Element method:

```
element.setAttribute("value","opaque");
```

So your code without jQuery should be like:

```
document.querySelector("param[name='wmode']").setAttribute("value","opaque");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, probably `param` is a class not an `element`

```
$(".param[name=wmode]").attr("value","opaque");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set attribute of any element by using setAttribute function. In your case it will be

document.getElementById('myelement').setAttribute('name', 'My_Element');

You can learn more about this at
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Thanks